# Converting upper and lower case letters

Tags: c++

In c++, how do I convert a capital letter to a small letter and back?

```
ch= ch-('a'-'A') a -> A
ch= ch+('a'-'A'). A-> a
```

Is there a "formula" like that one for converting a letter to a number and reversed?

Comment: 1. Your question is almost entirely unreadable. 2. What do you mean by "converting a letter to a number"?

Comment: Letters (`char` constants) are numbers actually.

Comment: This `digit = '1' - '0' -> digit == 1`? There is a difference between "number" and "digit".

Comment: In today's world of localization and Unicode, doing this in this manner isn't a good idea. If you're writing a tool for yourself, it might be okay.

Answer (score 3):

There are "formulas" to convert a lower case to upper case and vice versa.  They deal with adding or subtracting the the value of distance between `'A'` and `'a'`.  Instead of using them though we have [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower) and [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/toupper) which will handle the conversion.

Comment: Those formulas are **not** portable.

Comment: @PeteBecker they're portable *enough* - I've never used a system where that trick wouldn't work. But then again I've never needed to deal with accented characters.

Comment: They are portable as long as dealing with ASCII characters A-Z. It won't work for languages that use characters with accents/umlauts and other modifiers, and of course, not languages that use other writing symbols than "English". But assuming you are not working on code that has to work on a IBM system using EBCDIC, and only in English, then it'll work fine.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I had linked to the wrong versions.  I changed it to the `<locale>` versions as that is the more portable version.

Answer (score 1):

Converting a digit as a character to it's integer value can be done by `ch - '0'` - although I'm not 100% sure that's what you are asking for. Obviously, converting a string to a number means picking off the digits in the correct order and multiplying, to make the "whole" number.